# Un-escape specific characters when serializing to JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, character-encoding, system.text.json

I have a simple task which is to unescape an apostrophe when serializing to JSON using System.Text.JSON:

```
using System;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Unicode;

namespace DebugApp;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = new Item
        {
            Text = "'"
        };

        var encoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings();
        encoderSettings.AllowCharacters('\u0027', '\'');
        encoderSettings.AllowRange(UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin);
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(encoderSettings)
        };

        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(input, options);

        Console.WriteLine("Serialized json: {0}", json);
    }

    private class Item
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I expect the outcome to be `Serialized json: {"Text":"'"}`

Unfortunately, I am still getting `Serialized json: {"Text":"\u0027"}`

I referred to the Microsoft documentation here => [Serialize specific characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-encoding#serialize-specific-characters)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Further down the page `JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping`. There are characters that are escaped to prevent html / javascript from doing anything to the value.

Comment: Use Newtonsoft.Json and you will always be happy.

Comment: Same here, the Encoder JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping disables a wide range of character escpaping. I am looking for a solution that escapes only specific characters. Using Newtonsoft.Json is not an option.

Comment: Write your own encoder, copying most of the code from the source https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/DefaultJavaScriptEncoder.cs  Relevant also https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/65130

Comment: `JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping` works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/1E4nux

Comment: This seems to be intentional.   Looking at the source code, [`JavaScriptEncoder.Create(TextEncoderSettings settings)`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.4/src/libraries/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/JavaScriptEncoder.cs#L43) calls [`new DefaultJavaScriptEncoder(settings)`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.4/src/libraries/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/DefaultJavaScriptEncoder.cs#L17) which intentionally sets `allowMinimalJsonEscaping: false`.

Comment: Only `UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping => DefaultJavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedEscapingSingleton` which returns [`new DefaultJavaScriptEncoder(new TextEncoderSettings(UnicodeRanges.All), allowMinimalJsonEscaping: true);`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.4/src/libraries/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/DefaultJavaScriptEncoder.cs#L12) sets `allowMinimalJsonEscaping: true`.

Comment: If `JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping` is unacceptable because you need to control encoding ranges, then you could use the dark arts of reflection to create a `JavaScriptEncoder` with `allowMinimalJsonEscaping: true`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/QVetZq.  That seems to be the only option in .NET 6.

Answer (score 0):

Use Newtonsoft.Json and you always will be happy. But if you still want to use System.Text.Json , use this System.Text.RegularExpressions function

```
json = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(
         System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(input));
```

or more simple

```
 json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(input).Replace("\\u0027","'");
```

result

```
{"Text":"'"}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. However, that solution unescapes all forbidden characters.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not supported in the current version of .NET.

You could do this with your own encoder, but that would require rewriting huge chunks of code.

---

Instead, you can do this with some [rather](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/DefaultJavaScriptEncoder.cs) [nasty](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d58efd1f78c5f7b8e1df60dd5e67fafeae9526ee/src/libraries/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/OptimizedInboxTextEncoder.cs) [reflection](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d58efd1f78c5f7b8e1df60dd5e67fafeae9526ee/src/libraries/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/AllowedBmpCodePointsBitmap.cs). Please note that this code is quite brittle and likely to break on a different version of .NET. It doesn't work on .NET 4, as the [internal code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/bd30a3f458b6b0f71204fc3630b2d29b780c4167/src/System.Text.Encodings.Web/src/System/Text/Encodings/Web/JavaScriptEncoder.cs) is different.

```cs
 private static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var input = new Item
     {
         Text = "'"
     };

     var encoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings();
     encoderSettings.AllowRange(UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin);
     var encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.Create(encoderSettings);
     
     var innerEncoder = encoder.GetType().GetField("_innerEncoder", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(encoder);
     var codePoints = innerEncoder.GetType().GetField("_allowedBmpCodePoints", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(innerEncoder);
     codePoints.GetType().GetMethod("AllowChar").Invoke(codePoints, new object[]{ '\''});
     // codePoints is a struct so need to write it back
     innerEncoder.GetType().GetField("_allowedBmpCodePoints", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(innerEncoder, codePoints);

     var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
     {
         Encoder = encoder,
     };

     var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(input, options);

     Console.WriteLine("Serialized json: {0}", json);
 }

 private class Item
 {
     public string Text { get; set; }
 }
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C1wUvt)